# Jquery ajax Load catch any to display loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have a complex site with lots of jquery loads in various places and in different files.  I want to have a single method which renders a loading popup when any of the ajax loads run, without (hopefully) modifying them all.

Anyone know a way to 'catch' any ajax request start, and also the request end?

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing all your AJAX calls with the same API method or is it a mixture of jQuery.get, jQuery.post, jQuery.getJSON, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is register for the [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) events. These will fire for any jQuery ajax events.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The complete and beforeSend events to achieve the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: sorry no good wanted a global catchall (see answer from Bernhard Hofmann)